# Image Map Plugin for TinyMCE in joomla not working

Tags: joomla, tinymce, imagemap

I have installed the image-map plugin for Tiny MCE in Joomla 2.5.

It appears to be working alright in the backend. I have inserted an image in the article and created image map tags using the plugin button. 
The tags for image map appears to be correct

But when I am browsing in the front-end there seems to be no effect for the image map. Firebug shows the line image map area as disabled.

```
<p>
<img border="0" title="Ground Floor" src="/images/ground-floor.jpg">
<map id="imgmap2012831174531" name="imgmap2012831174531">

<area target="_blank" href="/mywebsolutions.co.in" coords="212,934,294,1058"  alt="MYWEB SOLUTIONS" shape="rect">
</map>
The line with
<area target..... appears faded.
</p>
```

I have tried everything including installing a jquery no conflict plugin.

Comment: could you provide a link to your site please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<object data="images/sampledata/fruitshop/map.png" usemap="#map" border="0">
</object>
<map id="map" name="Map">
```

- Map id should be same to `usemap` id.
- You have to given the src in object tag. Then it will works fine..

All the best....

Comment: Yes, not exactly but  you hind that Map ID and usemap id should be same did helped me. Actually I didn't included any usemap parameter in the img tag.

Comment: Also You should include the "usemap" as valid element id in Tinymce plugin settings and also edit the /plugins/editors/tinymce.php to include the "usemap" element under images section to prevent Tinymce from stripping the usemap="#map"

Answer (score 0):

area tag must be closed properly like,

`<area target="_blank" href="/mywebsolutions.co.in" coords="212,934,294,1058"  alt="MYWEB SOLUTIONS" shape="rect" />`

or

`<area target="_blank" href="/mywebsolutions.co.in" coords="212,934,294,1058"  alt="MYWEB SOLUTIONS" shape="rect"></area>`

One more thing you should not use TineMCE for this function, select CodeMirror or None in site setting, it will definitely work. after saving particular post you can change back to tineMCE. Remember not to edit same on TinyMCE in future, else it will remove your functionality.